# Can I replace % 20 with & nbsp in URLs that have spaces?

Tags: html, url, encoding, character-encoding

Within my HTML, can I use the character entity reference "`&nbsp;`" in place of "`%20`" in Web URLs?

They're both spaces, right?

Comment: What possible reason could you have for wanting to do this in the first place? I have a feeling I don't want to know...

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Pup: The problem here is that URLs and HTML are two completely separate things that conform to different rules. You can't assume that a rule for one system is automatically true for the other, just because they are used in conjunction.

Comment: @Tomalak: actually, HTML character entity references *do* work in URLs that appear in HTML. I've noticed that many people are confused about this. The browser will convert all character entity references to the characters they refer to in attributes including URI attributes like href and src. In fact, when you write "http://example.com/?foo=bar&baz=quux" in HTML it's technically invalid because you should actually write &amp;, not &. The number of people I've encountered over the years that think "&amp;" in a URL within an HTML document will send 5 characters to the server is astonishing.

Comment: Yes, it's shocking :) In this scenario, my file's name is the most important thing here. I'm linking to my file on a Web page, and I want to preserve the name's spaces, so it reads "My Very Readable Filename.zip" after it's been downloaded.

Comment: @Pup: The name of a downloaded file is best preserved in the "filename" parameter of "Content-Disposition" HTTP header.

Comment: Note that spaces and non-breaking spaces are two different things. The latter tells HTML that you want to display a space, but "act" as if it's not a space, ie pretend this "space" is another letter of the alphabet: do not wrap onto a new line (non-breaking space) "here". This prevents awkward layout such as an address house number appearing at the end of one line, then the street name appearing at the start of a new line, for example. Using `&nbsp;` instead of ` `, between the number and street name will wrap before the number, so both appear on the new line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is, they are both used to represent "spaces", but they represent *different* spaces.

`%20` is the URL escaping for byte 32, which corresponds to plain old space in pretty much any encoding you're likely to use in a URL.

`&nbsp;` is an HTML character reference which actually refers to character 160 of Unicode (and also ISO-8859-1 aka Latin-1). It's a different space character entirely -- the "non-breaking space". Even though they look pretty much the same, they're different characters and it's unlikely that your server will treat them the same way.

Comment: Differences between these two types of space representations aside, do you know if html character entity references are permitted in URLs, either per the spec or in practical implementations?

Comment: @Matt Yes and no. HTML character entity references are permitted in URLs *within HTML documents*. In fact, ampersands in URLs in HTML documents are supposed to be HTML-escaped. Having "`http://example.com/foo?bar=1&baz=2`" in HTML is actually invalid. It should be "`http://example.com/foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2`". That said, the HTML entity reference isn't really "in the URL". It's in the HTML's representation of that URL. The URL itself just has `&` where the HTML contains `&amp;`.

Comment: @Matt Almost forgot: I believe ancient versions of MSIE would attempt to use HTML character entity references in form submissions for characters that could not be represented in the character set being used for the form submission. This was not standards compliant at all, which isn't too surprising for MSIE.

Comment: Really interesting.  I thought this point was especially good: 'That said, the HTML entity reference isn't really "in the URL". It's in the HTML's representation of that URL.'  Given what you said in the comments here, you might want to update your answer to distinguish between usage in URLs in the browser address bar vs. within HTML documents.  The OP's question doesn't distinguish, but given your comments it is a critical difference.

Answer (score 6):

No. Neither are spaces (technically). Both *represent* spaces in different ways though. Make every effort to NOT have spaces, or representatives of spaces, in your URLs. Many find it more elegant (me included) to replace spaces with _ or -

Comment: Depending on your point of view, that's not quite correct.  `%20` represents a space, but `&nbsp;` represents a *non-breaking* space, technically a separate character.  So even if it were a good idea to use HTML escaping in URLs, this wouldn't work because it would replace one character with another, changing the meaning of the URL.

Comment: How does that differ from my answer?

Comment: The don't just represent spaces in different ways, the represent different spaces.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. But they still represent spaces - which is what I said.

Answer (score 4):

No.  &nbsp; is an HTML non-breaking-space entity; this entity has no meaning when used in a filesystem or wherever else that a URL might point.  URLs are not encoded in HTML.

Comment: You can have non-breaking spaces in filenames, at least in some filesystems. It's probably not a good idea, but saying "this entity has no meaning when used in a filesystem" is going a bit too far. It's just another character. (And if you're referring to the entity reference, &nbsp;, he was talking about using this in HTML, so the browser would take care of converting the entity reference to the corresponding character.)

Answer (score 3):

No, not in the URLs. What you *can* do is replace spaces in the textual representation of the URL.

So instead of:

```
<a href="http://some.site/doc%20with%20spaces">http://some.site/doc%20with%20spaces</a>
```

you can have:

```
<a href="http://some.site/doc%20with%20spaces">http://some.site/doc&nbsp;with&nbsp;spaces</a>
```

Comment: Does anyone know why the `&nbsp;` that I have in the lower sample does not show up? It used to, I'm sure...

Comment: Because it was turned into a space! Use &amp;nbsp; for it to show up properly.

Comment: Snap! You really think that's the cause? ;-) Seriously - I thought that a "code" section was to display it's contents *verbatim*. And I thought it did that until recently. Now if I write `&amp;nbsp;`, I fear that this will show up at some point...

Answer (score 2):

%20 is what you get with URL encoding, so this is what you should use if you are going to use it in a URL.

&nbsp; is a HTML entity, which is what should be used for 'non breaking space' in an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Most persons try to absolutely avoid spaces in their filenames in URLs. They will give you a serious headache every time so try to do so.

If you want to have spaces in an URL you have to encode them with %20.

&nbsp is used by the browser to know how to display the page. This information is only used for displaying. The %20 will be sent to the server that manages all the stuff needed to transfer the webpage to your visitors. The server doesn't speak html so the server would interpret &nbsp as a normal part of the filenname and search for a file called in the way foo bar. This file will not be found. Much worse the web server will think that the & begins the variable part of the url and only search for the page foo and then try to generate a variable nbsp and a variable bar but he want see any values for them. All in all the web server can't handle a URL with an   in it.

Comment: The server doesn't speak HTML, but he was talking abut using this in his HTML. The browser *does* interpret character references in attributes, including URLs, and so the &nbsp; will turn into a non-breaking space. The server will never see the & (or the "nbsp;", for that matter).

Comment: Ok so the server will see a normal white space. That is also a bad thing :)

Comment: No, it'll see a non-breaking-space character. It's a different character from normal space.

Answer (score -1):

Neither are spaces. You shouldnt be using spaces but if for what ever reason you can't avoid it you should just be able to do...

```
<a href="Web Page.aspx">Hey there</a>
```

...clicking on which will automatically navigate the user to

```
WebSite/Web%20Page.aspx
```